# Super Hexagon point -> hexagon progression meaning

Tags: super-hexagon

Each stage divided into six “levels” called Point, Line, Triangle, Square, Pentagon, and Hexagon that you reach at regular time intervals. Is there some meaning behind level names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Point, line*, triangle, square, pentagon and hexagon are geometric shapes with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 points respectively. I guess the designer though it would be more fun than calling them "level 1", "level 2", "level 3" etc.

*actually, a line is infinite and has no points, it should be "point, segment, triangle" instead.

Comment: They call it line because segment sounds too outta sync with the rest of the game.